# Google Weather API and Using Custom image

Tags: php, api, weather, weather-api, google-weather-api

I am using Google weather API and PHP for fetch conditions:

```
http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=New%20York
```

Is there any way for change:

```
<icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"/>
```

to custom image?

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `<icon data="/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif"/>` is returned by the API (which is not an official API btw.) you could use an if statement in PHP to "replace" the image.

```
if($theAPIResponse->icon->attributes()->data == '/ig/images/weather/partly_cloudy.gif') {
       // Override the nodes data attribute with your custom image
       $theAPIResponse->icon->attributes()->data = '/path/to/your/custom_image.gif';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using `str_replace("google_path","your_path")`.

Comment: Hi! If you want to show that something is code you should enclose it in backticks (`\`your code\``) or, if it is a large block of code, indent it by four spaces. That way your post will be easier to read.